# Is the GeoWebCache S3 Blob Store only for use with preseeded tiles?

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I'm thinking about moving over to the S3 blobstore, but it looks like it only works with preseeded layers which isn't an option for me.

Is it possible to use the S3 blobstore and have the cache built on the fly?